# Selenium/Webdriver tests execution time doubled after upgrading to 2.45

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, automated-tests, selenium-firefoxdriver

after the upgrade from selenium 2.44 to 2.45 the execution time is 2-3 times longer than before. I have been executing the tests with Firefox 36 in a Linux/Ubuntu and a Windows XP environment.

What could be the reason behind this slower speed? Do I have to configure FirefoxDriver differently or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a **known issue** with the FirefoxDriver 2.45, see https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=8551

Until it gets fixed the workaround is to downgrade Firefox & selenium.

BTW: Don't forget to star this issue at google code! Maybe it will help to speed up the fix ;-)

Comment: @donfuaxx This is probably not related. But, I am kind of struggling with some tests that run fine on `Chrome`, `Firefox` and `IE11` But, do not work on `IE8` winxp. Can you please suggest me if there is anything special in terms `DesireCapabilities` or other setup?